# Runtime Error - Google Code Jam 2019 Qualifier - Scala

Tags: scala

I am attempting to submit a solution to Foregone Solution in the 2019 Google Code Jam Qualification Round Archives. I am new to Scala. My code runs to completion through IntelliJ. Is anybody aware of what may be causing a Runtime Error when I submit the below code to the Google Code Jam server?

```
import scala.io.StdIn
object main extends App {
  val T = StdIn.readInt
  var firstCheck: String = ""
  var secondCheck: String = ""
  var N: String = ""
  for (i <- 1 to T) {
    N = StdIn.readLine()
    for (j <- 0 until N.length) {
      if (N(j) == '4') secondCheck += "1"
      else if (secondCheck != "") secondCheck += "0"
    }
    firstCheck = N.replaceAll("[4]", "3")
    println(s"Case #$i: $firstCheck $secondCheck")
    secondCheck = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem this code is supposed to solve?

Comment: @jrook https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/0000000000088231

Comment: Which Runtime Error are you seeing? And wouldn't this return a bad result for `N = "343"`?

Comment: @jwvh You are right! I will need to move replaceAll below the for loop and search on '4' instead of '3' inside the for loop. Nice catch! As for the Runtime Error, I do not know which error. Code Jam's service does not specify which errors it throws in order to prevent giving certain languages an advantage.